# How to save dynamicly created template in database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates

I would like to enable users to create their own templates in my asp.net mvc web application.
For example, you would create a simple template like a log on control,  2 labels, 2 textboxes, and 1 submit button.

Is it possible to allow users to save such templates in a database and then use them/extend them later?  Could you please give me an example or link that shows how someone already did something similar?

I have no idea how to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may give you some pointers http://mihkeltt.blogspot.com/2009/12/nvelocity-template-engine-sample.html